# How to get only the current thread number?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

This is the example code I am using

```
import time
import threading
import re

def do_action():
    while True:
        x = threading.current_thread()
        print(x)
        time.sleep(60)

for _ in range(1):
    threading.Thread(target=do_action).start()
```

The result of Print is as follows

```
<Thread(Thread-1, started 10160)>
```

I need to get only the number of the Thread which in this case is the number 1

I tried to use

```
thread_number = re.findall("(\d+)", x)[0]
```

But error occurs when using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1` in the `Thread-1` output is part of the default thread name generation if you don't explicitly give your thread a name. There is **no guarantee** that a thread will have such a number - the main thread won't, and explicitly named threads typically won't. Also, multiple threads can have the same number, if a thread is manually given a name that matches the `Thread-n` pattern.

If that's the number you want, you can get it by parsing the thread's name - `int(thread.name.split('-')[1])` - but it's probably not the best tool for whatever job you plan to use it for.

---

If you're starting a bunch of threads and they each need to use a distinct number from 1 to n for some reason, maybe work allocation or something, just pass a number to their target function:

```
def do_stuff(n):
    # do stuff with n

threads = [threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(i,)) for i in range(1, 11)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
```

Threads also have `ident` and `native_id` attributes, which are `None` for threads that haven't been started yet and integers for threads that have started. These are identifiers that are guaranteed to be distinct for threads alive at the same time - this distinctness guarantee is process-wide for `ident` and system-wide for `native_id`. However, if one thread finishes before another starts, they may be assigned the same `ident` or `native_id`.

Comment: I'm going to use a lot of threads, yes, I'm starting with python and I want to go deeper.

I would like to get the number just to try something, but what I really need is to have the threads read the line of a file separately.

example: I have a txt file with 100 lines, and each line contains 1 user, password

I will open 100 threads that will perform a login using user, password but I would like to define for each thread to use only 1 line.

thread 1 uses line 1 of txt
thread 2 uses line 2 of txt

and so it goes...

Comment: @DonCorleone: That's a job for just passing each thread an integer manually. Otherwise, you're relying on these threads being the *only* threads in your program with default-generated names, which is an incredibly fragile, inextensible design.

Comment: Can you help me with this? show example in code?

Comment: I did! That code block in my answer is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
thread_number = re.findall("(\d+)", x.name)[0]
```